# How to import a file from localhost into Docker?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I want to open a folder from my host machine in the Jupyter notebook application (like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3bk2pojLoU). I tried some different versions of `docker run -it --rm --name tf -v /Users/superuser/mywork:/notebooks -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter`, but it doesn't work. Something must be wrong, but I don't get what it is.

Thanks for every answer (Y)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what exactly do you mean? You cannot see the folder `/notebooks` in the container or the content is different from the local host folder `/Users/superuser/mywork`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to speculate, but I think what you mean by 'it doesn't work' is that you do not see the `mywork` folder from the host in the file list within the Web UI of the jupiter. If that it the case, what you want to do/try is mount the volume to the `/tf` folder, ie

```
docker run -it --rm --name tf \
-v /Users/superuser/mywork:/tf/notebooks \
-p 8888:8888 \
-p 6006:6006 \
tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter
```

Comment: You speculated correct. Oh what an annoying mistake I tried the directorys tf and notebooks alone, but not in one path. Thank you